# Userdefined number format in excel shows just hashes

Tags: excel

I have a few cells with numbers:

[image: Excel cells unformatted]

I gave them the format `#.##0 "Mio. Liter"`. So, for example, the number `8145369` becomes `8.145.369 Mio. Liter`:

[image: Excel formatting dialog]

However, the cells just show hashes:

[image: Excel cells formatted (broken)]

When I hover a cell, the correct format (`8.145.369 Mio. Liter`) is shown in the hover info.

How can I display the numbers correctly formatted?

Comment: Make the column wider.

Comment: @NilsLindemann it's not about *programming* though. It's better suited for https://superuser.com/. "Make the column wider" isn't a programming answer either. No DV from me, but definitely a vote to move to super user.

Comment: While it is a question excel beginners can fall for, your title in google gives "The most common reason is because the numbers are too large to display in the cell so you need to increase the column width." and would've saved you time and effort :)

Comment: @Notus_Panda I searched for "excel benutzerdefiniertes format sehe nur ####", "excel benutzerdefiniertes format wird nicht übernommen", "excel benutzerdefiniertes format zeigt nur "#" an". Then I asked here. Is that "I tried" enough?

Comment: @BigBen I asked the last excel questions here too and no one complained. At the moment of asking I was not aware that the problem has such a simple solution ;-)

Comment: Excel won't show parts of numbers as some people won't realize the number is not complete. If you are designing a bridge and don't use the correct values it gets to be a safety issue...

Comment: As a hint for the future: since this (and most) sites who are there to help everyone around the world are in English, best to search in English as well, maybe until the AI kicks in enough to auto-translate when you don't get enough hits ^^

Comment: @NilsLindemann your last question was about formulas. That's definitely closer to programming than "widen a column". Even if you're not aware of the non-programming nature of the question/answer, that's why there are close votes to migrate this question to Super User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make the column wider. A column containing a number must be wide enough for it to display its formatted value or you will see hash marks (unlike with text).